# Is there any error which results in displaying incorrect average waiting time?

Tags: java, swing

I have coded non-preemptive priority scheduling algorithm in java with GUI. Initially it asks user to enter total number of processes and then text fields and labels are created as per number of processes entered by user. After clicking on confirm button it displays average waiting time. Though it is not giving errors but it is displaying incorrect average waiting time. Is there any errors/changes required to get correct average waiting time?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class fcfs extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton jb[] = new JButton[3];
    JTextField jt1[], jt2[];
    JLabel jl[], jl1, jl2, jl3;
    JPanel jp, jp1;
    Container con;
    int k, p;
    String str[] = { "SUBMIT", "RESET", "EXIT" };
    String str1[] = { "Process", "   AT", "ST", "WT", "TAT" };
    int x, i, j, a, b, e, f, pos;

    public fcfs() {
        super("Non-preemptive Priority scheduling algoritham");
        con = getContentPane();
        k = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of process"));
        jl1 = new JLabel("Process");
        jl2 = new JLabel("Arival Time");
        jl3 = new JLabel("Burst Time");
        jl = new JLabel[k];
        jt1 = new JTextField[k];
        jt2 = new JTextField[k];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            jl[i] = new JLabel("process" + (i + 1));
            jt1[i] = new JTextField(10);
            jt2[i] = new JTextField(10);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            jb[i] = new JButton(str[i]);
        }
        con.setLayout(new GridLayout(k + 2, 3));
        con.add(jl1);
        con.add(jl2);
        con.add(jl3);
        int l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            con.add(jl[l]);
            con.add(jt1[l]);
            con.add(jt2[l]);
            l++;
        }
        l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            con.add(jb[l]);
            jb[l].addActionListener(this);
            l++;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int FT[] = new int[k];
        int WT[] = new int[k];
        int TAT[] = new int[k];
        int FT1[] = new int[k];
        float NTAT[] = new float[k];
        float s = 0;
        float avg;
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jp = new JPanel();
        jp1 = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(k + 1, 7));
        jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        if (ae.getSource() == jb[2]) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (ae.getSource() == jb[0]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                pos = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < k; j++) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(jt1[j].getText()) < Integer.parseInt(jt1[pos].getText())) {
                        pos = j;
                    }
                }
                a = Integer.parseInt(jt1[i].getText());
                b = Integer.parseInt(jt1[pos].getText());
                x = a;
                a = b;
                b = x;

                FT[i] = Integer.parseInt(jt2[i].getText());
                FT[pos] = Integer.parseInt(jt2[pos].getText());
                x = FT[i];
                FT[i] = FT[pos];
                FT[pos] = x;

            }

            WT[0] = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
                WT[i] = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    WT[i] = WT[i] + FT[j];
                }
                s = s + WT[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                jp.add(new JLabel(str1[i]));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                jp.add(new JLabel("process" + (i + 1)));
                jp.add(new JLabel("   " + Integer.parseInt(jt1[i].getText())));
                jp.add(new JLabel("" + Integer.parseInt(jt2[i].getText())));
                jp.add(new JLabel("" + WT[i]));

                jp.add(new JLabel("" + TAT[i]));

            }
            avg = s / k;
            String str2 = "Average Waiting Time is " + avg;
            jp1.add(new JLabel(str2));
            main.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            main.add(jp1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, main, "output", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } else if (ae.getSource() == jb[1]) {
            setVisible(false);
            fcfs window = new fcfs();
            window.setSize(400, 300);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fcfs window = new fcfs();
        window.setSize(400, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: For our benefit and yours, please put in some effort to format your code well before posting it. Reading and understanding someone else's code is hard enough by itself, why make it harder than it has to be by posting poorly formatted, hard to read code? Also what have you done to debug your problem?

Comment: OK, I've edited your post, but again please clarify what you've done to debug your problem and what information your debugging sessions brought you. You will want to focus your question more on the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please describe what output you expect, and what output you see.

Comment: To make your code easier to follow please use descriptive names rather than `x, i, j, a, b, e, f, k,p,FT` etc.